# Wireless wire ethernet

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet

So my problem is that I have this ethernet connection between two devices, where the cable needs to run through a working environment and not constantly to the same location.
What I would like is to make this connection wireless.
I do not know what type of connection is transported over the connection.
My idea at this point is to have 2 boxes, both with an ethernet connector (RJ45) and an antenna, which always talk to eachother 1 on 1.
Therefore it should be pretty much plug and play.

Anyone knows if this sort of connection is used anywhere and how anyone would call it, cause an extensive google search did not result in anything (at least for me).

Comment: You're basically describing how regular wifi works. But what kind of devices do you have? Do they use regular computer networking communication? Some things (like security cameras) can use power over ethernet cables, or you could have any custom weirdness.

Comment: Alright, so the idea is that in our car workshop a car is connected to a pc using an OBD-ethernet adapter and an ethernet cable, because of this, we have to run the cable over the floor of the working environment, making people trip. Range will never be more than about 15 meters, so not a lot is required and my budget is very low (around 15-20 euros total).
Therefore the point-to-point bridge is a good idea, but way overkill in this scenario, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Foitn: Ah, at that price you can _probably_ find something under the name of a "wireless range extender" – quite a few models can be switched to a WiFi client/station mode, leaving the Ethernet port for the computer. (I'll update the post eventually...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, usually one would use Wi-Fi for that. The only question is what you need to connect and what distance

---

For long distance links, **point-to-point bridges** are *very* common; especially among wireless ISPs in a point-to-multipoint configuration, hence sometimes also called **wireless CPEs**.

Physically, they usually come with an integrated directional antenna (e.g. [1](https://docs.nycmesh.net/img/nsm5/roof-87.jpg) the entire flat front is the antenna), or with a connector for an external one. Almost all can be powered using PoE.

Networking-wise, they're mostly standard Wi-Fi devices with WDS/4addr mode – providing a clean connection which can carry everything that Ethernet could (even VLANs), and even preserving MAC addresses on both ends (which an ordinary wireless router wouldn't allow).

If your desired range is below 10 km, you'll be fine with a cheap model with an integrated antenna. (I think the average price for a single device (LigoWave, Mikrotik, TP-Link, Ubiquiti) is around €80.)

Everything works as regular Wi-Fi: configure both devices with the same channel/SSID/PSK; configure one as the "access-point" and the other as "client/station"; and point them at each other. (Although, depending on country, special radio licensing rules might apply.)

---

> Alright, so the idea is that in our car workshop a car is connected to a pc using an OBD-ethernet adapter and an ethernet cable, because of this, we have to run the cable over the floor of the working environment, making people trip. Range will never be more than about 15 meters, so not a lot is required and my budget is very low (around 15-20 euros total). Therefore the point-to-point bridge is a good idea, but way overkill in this scenario, as far as I can see.

Yes,  now that you've specified the situation in the comments, it is somewhat overkill (something cheap from eBay would still work though).

Another similar device type is a **range extender**. (I think that's the current name?) which is the same but omnidirectional and short-range; essentially a wireless bridge for consumer market.

While they are mainly meant to act as a Wi-Fi access point from Ethernet uplink, I've seen many models can be *reconfigured* to do the opposite – connect as a client to your existing Wi-Fi network and provide Ethernet instead.

If you don't have an existing Wi-Fi network, create one. Either a second 'range extender' in access-point mode, or a full "wireless router", will do the job. (They **don't need** Internet access for the local network to work. Even a router is not needed.)

---

Finally... If you want to connect a PC to Wi-Fi, you can simply add a Wi-Fi adapter directly to the PC. If it's a desktop, you can install a PCI or PCIe card, or connect a USB Wi-Fi adapter.

If it's an old laptop, it'll have either USB, or at least a CardBus/PCMCIA SLOT for inserting a Wi-Fi card.

Comment: I think the second idea would be the wisest, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on distance between access points and the wiring system, you might be able to use powerline networking devices. These plug into your regular power outlets and talk to one another over the normal wiring. Some of them are simple wifi access points, some also include one or more ethernet port(s).  Google will show you examples if you ask it for "powerline network adapter" (w/o the quote marks)

Comment: Good solution, although we are not always near the same power grid, as in, it might be a different group for the fuses, therefore it might not work.

Comment: As I understand it, as long as you're on the same side of a transformer, it should work. In my setup, I've got two of these on entirely different circuits from the source and it works nicely. The things are also quite inexpensive, so testing a couple of them out wouldn't be a bank-breaker.